# How can I see the employee IDs for a project that lasts longer than 20 hours per week?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, where-clause

*(assigned_name in works_on is percentage of time employee is assigned to project)*

Question:
Find the IDs of employees assigned to a project that is more than 20 hours per week.

My attempt:

I have assumed 24 hours as working hours here. Is my query correct?
Here's the create and insert statements.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employees(
    employee_id NUMERIC(9),
    first_name VARCHAR(10),
    last_name VARCHAR(20),
    dept_code CHAR(5),
    salary NUMERIC(9, 2),
    PRIMARY KEY (employee_id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS departments(
    code CHAR(5),
    name VARCHAR(30),
    manager_id NUMERIC(9),
    sub_dept_of CHAR(5),
    PRIMARY KEY (code)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS projects(
    project_id CHAR(8),
    dept_code CHAR(5),
    description VARCHAR(200),
    start_date DATE,
    stop_date DATE,
    revenue NUMERIC(12, 2),
    PRIMARY KEY (project_id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS works_on(
    employee_id NUMERIC(9),
    project_id CHAR(8),
    assigned_time NUMERIC(3, 2),
    PRIMARY KEY (employee_id, project_id)
);

INSERT INTO employees
VALUES (1, 'Al', 'Betheleader', 'ADMIN', 70000),
       (2, 'Pl', 'Rsquared', 'ACCNT', 40000),
       (3, 'Harry', 'Hardware', 'HDWRE', 50000),
       (4, 'Sussie', 'Software', 'CNSLT', 60000),
       (5, 'Abe', 'Advice', 'CNSLT', 30000),
       (6, 'Hardly', 'Aware', NULL, 65000),
       (7, 'Bucky', 'Nour', 'ACTNG', 25000);
 

INSERT INTO departments
VALUES ('ADMIN', 'Administration', 1, NULL),
       ('ACCNT', 'Accounting', 2, 'ADMIN'),
       ('HDWRE', 'Hardware', 3, 'CNSLT'),
       ('CNSLT', 'Consulting', 4, 'ADMIN'),
       ('ACTNG', 'Bug fixing', 7, 'ADMIN');

INSERT INTO projects
VALUES 
('EMPHAPPY', 'ADMIN', 'Employee Moral', '2002-03-14', NULL, 0),
('ADT4MFIA', 'ACCNT', 'Mofia Audit', '2003-07-03', '2003-11-30', 100000),
('ROBOSPSE', 'CNSLT', 'Robotic Spouse', '2002-03-14', NULL, 242000),
('DNLDCLNT', 'CNSLT', 'Download Client', '2005-02-03', NULL, 18150),
('BOBBYFUN', 'ACTNG', 'Bug fixing', '2024-02-14', NULL, 17990);

INSERT INTO works_on
VALUES (2, 'ADT4MFIA', 0.50),
       (3, 'ROBOSPSE', 0.75),
       (4, 'ROBOSPSE', 0.75),
       (5, 'ROBOSPSE', 0.50),
       (5, 'ADT4MFIA', 0.60),
       (3, 'DNLDCLNT', 0.25);
```

```
SELECT employee_id
FROM works_on
WHERE 1.68 * assigned_time > 20;
```

Comment: share sample output

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin As per the query, I am getting an empty output.

Comment: Take out the test and include 1.68 * assigned_time in the select - are any over 20?

Answer (score 0):

while you mention that you're looking for person > 20hr per week, you don't give us information about what the "assigned_time" is in reference to. Is that a percentage of each day, week, month? With the values you have now, you can see that none of these individuals is close to a value of '20' if you just add your math to the select statement.

```
SELECT employee_id, (assigned_time * 1.68) as'worked'
FROM works_on


employee_id worked
       2    0.8400
       3    0.4200
       3    1.2600
       4    1.2600
       5    1.0080
       5    0.8400
```

I imagine you're looking for the sum of same employee id's working multiple times, which would be more along the lines of

```
SELECT employee_id, sum(assigned_time * 1.68) as'worked'
FROM works_on
group by employee_id



employee_id worked
       2    0.8400
       3    1.6800
       4    1.2600
       5    1.8480
```

Comment: you can play with values and such here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=852e1fe4b13e32d82ff403d95b51f29b